# Vue 3 composition API with updating refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am passing a ref value to a composable function, `updateableSetting`. This has an initial value, `settingA`, but can be updated by the user. When updated, us it possible to have `useFeature` run again and return an updated `feature` value?

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const updateableSetting = ref('settingA')
    const { feature } = useFeature(updateableSetting.value)
  }
})
```

Comment: please share the code of `useFeature`

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use a computed property

```js
import { ref, defineComponent, computed} from 'vue'

const useFeature = (initialRef) => {
  const feature = computed(() => initialRef.value + ' - I am always up to date!')
  return {
    feature
  }
}

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const updateableSetting = ref('settingA')

    //make sure you don't pass .value here - pass the whole ref object instead
    const { feature } = useFeature(updateableSetting) 

    return { feature }
  }
})
```

If you mean "run a function everytime updatedValue changes", you can use

```js
watch(
   [updatedValue], 
   () => {console.log('updatedValue changed! doing some calculations...')}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when using composables in nuxt 3.
In nuxt 3 new reactive state is available called `useState`. try `useState` instead of `ref`.
for more information see nuxt 3 document: [useState nuxt3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/usage/state/)